# Room frozen after 1 day of inactivity

Tags: bug, chat

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator

The room above is to always stay open. I unfroze it when I noticed it was frozen (after 15 days). It passed that threshold again, I unfroze it again (yay for not needing moderators!)

However, this week, it froze after only **one** day. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Unfreezing doesn't count as new activity in a room: you have to post a message in the room after unfreezing to get 14 days. The script that freezes inactive rooms runs once every 24 hours.